# How to write a schema validation for the following data?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, backend, joi

I have been trying to write schema validation using Joi for the following input data using Joi data validator.

```
{
  "submissionReason": "new TPV required",
  "alignerInfo": {
    "name": "UPPER",
    "value": [
      {
        "name": "set",
        "value": "18/20"
      },
      {
        "name": "zenStage",
        "value": "2"
      }
    ]
  },
  "archesToTreat": "BOTH",
  "refinementGoals": [
    {
      "name": "Alignment"
    },
    {
      "name": "Close Residual Space",
      "value": [
        {
          "position": [
            "2.1",
            "2.2"
          ],
          "value": "0.5"
        },
        {
          "position": [
            "2.4",
            "2.5"
          ],
          "value": "0.7"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Resolve posterior Open Bite",
      "value": [
        {
          "name": "Attachments Only",
          "value": {
            "name": "teeth Attachment",
            "value": [
              "2.1",
              "2.2"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "Add Button for elastic",
          "value": [
            "2.1",
            "2.2"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "attachments": "keep all previous attachment and change",
  "iprInfo": {
    "name": "ipr not performed as prescibed",
    "value": [
      {
        "position": [
          "2.1",
          "2.2"
        ],
        "value": "0.5"
      }
    ]
  },
  "specialNotes": "Doctor Notes"
}
```

This is what I have written so far

```
Joi.object({
  submissionReason: Joi.string().required(),
  alignerInfo: Joi.object({
    name: Joi.string().required(),
    value: Joi.array().items(Joi.object({
      name: Joi.string().required(),
      value: Joi.string().required(),
    })).required()
  }).required(),
  archesToTreat: Joi.string().valid('UPPER', 'LOWER', 'BOTH').required(),
  refinementGoals: Joi.array().items(Joi.object({
    name: Joi.string().required(),
    value: Joi.array().items(Joi.object({
      position: Joi.array().items(Joi.string().required()).required(),
      value: Joi.string().required(),
      name: Joi.string().forbidden()
    })).when('name', {
      is: 'Close Residual Space',
      then: Joi.required(),
      otherwise: Joi.forbidden()
    })
  })).required(),
  attachments: Joi.string().required(),
  iprInfo: Joi.object({
    name: Joi.string().required(),
    value: Joi.array().items(Joi.object({
      position: Joi.array().items(Joi.string().required()).required(),
      value: Joi.string().required()
    })).required()
  }).required(),
  specialNotes: Joi.string().required()
})
```

But this is not working and i am getting the following error,

Validation Error: "refinementGoals[2].value" is not allowed

Please help me with the correct validation

Comment: You can use express-validator which provides schema based validation that suits your usecase. Here is a link of schema method of express-validator. https://express-validator.github.io/docs/api/check-schema

Answer (score 0):

Your validation is allowing 2 levels of `value`:

```
1- the first one is an array of objects
2- the second one is a string
```

But your sample object's refinementGoals's value has 3 levels:

```
1- first is an array (ok)
2- second is an object (invalid, only string is acceptable)
3- third is an array of strings (invalid, not defined in the schema)
```

I suggest using [joi.alternatives](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.9.1#alternatives) which allows you to set more than one type as valid type. Something like this:

```
value: Joi.alternatives().try(Joi.object(), Joi.array(), Joi.string());
```

**Update:**

Well, I checked closely your sample object and gotta say your schema match it.

1- In your schema.refinementGoals rules, only if `name` is `Close Residual Space`, `value` is required() else it's forbidden(), but in your sample object, `value` exists for all names.

2- You have made `position` required() and `name` forbidden() in the nested objects which, again, is opposite to the sample.

3- Your schema only allows string for the nested `value`, but in the sample it has `string`, `array` and `object` as its value.

I modified your schema rules for `refinementGoals` part to match your sample object, removed above-mentioned rules and this is the result. It worked after the changes.

```
refinementGoals: Joi.array()
.items(
  Joi.object({
    name: Joi.string().required(),
    value: Joi.array().items(
      Joi.object({
        position: Joi.array().items(Joi.string().required()),
        value: Joi.alternatives().try(
          Joi.string().required(),
          Joi.array().items(Joi.string().required()),
          Joi.object({
            name: Joi.string(),
            value: Joi.array().items(Joi.string().required()),
          })
        ),
        name: Joi.string(),
      })
    ),
  })
)
.required(),
```

Comment: could you give me the correct validation for the data?

Comment: @DrDoom, updated the answer and included a modified schema